# How to draw transparent trails using PIXI.js?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I've started playing with [PIXI.js](https://pixijs.github.io/docs) and tried to port this basic actionscript 3 snippet:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

var trails:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0x00000000);//create a transparent bitmap to draw the trails into
var trailsFade:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,1,1,0.25,0,0,0,1);//color transform: keep rgb the same(1,1,1), set alpha to 0.025 out of 1.0
var background:Bitmap = addChild(new Bitmap(trails,PixelSnapping.AUTO,true)) as Bitmap;//add the trails pixels/bitmap data into a Bitmap/display object at the bottom of the display list

var dot:Sprite = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
dot.graphics.lineStyle(3);
dot.graphics.drawCircle(-4, -4, 8);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(e:Event):void{
    dot.x = mouseX;
    dot.y = mouseY;
    //draw trails of the dot
    trails.draw(dot,dot.transform.concatenatedMatrix,trailsFade);//draw the dot into the bitmap data using the dot's transformation (x,y, rotation, scale)
}
```

What it does is draws a circle and takes a snapshot of it into a BitmapData object and there is a ColorMatrix filter applied with a small alpha/transparency value.

I've noticed PIXI.js has a lot of similarities and there is a [ColorMatrixFilter](https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.filters.ColorMatrixFilter.html) available, but I couldn't figure out what the equivalent of BitmapData.draw() is in PIXI.js. The closest thing I found is the [RenderTexture demo](http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=demos&f=render-texture-demo.js&title=RenderTexture&v=v3.0.11)

Based on that I've tried to port the as3 code above:

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(640, 480);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

 var stage = new PIXI.Container();
 
 var dot = new PIXI.Graphics();
 dot.beginFill(0xFF9900);
 dot.drawCircle(-8,-8,16);
 dot.endFill();
 stage.addChild(dot);

 var renderTexture = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
 var renderTexture2 = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
 var currentTexture = renderTexture;

 var outputSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(currentTexture);
 stage.addChild(outputSprite);


 animate();

 function animate() {
  var a = Date.now() * 0.001;
  dot.x = renderer.width * 0.5 + (Math.cos(a) * 200);
  dot.y = renderer.height * 0.5 + (Math.sin(a) * 200);

  // swap the buffers ...
     var temp = renderTexture;
     renderTexture = renderTexture2;
     renderTexture2 = temp;

     renderTexture2.render(stage, null, false);

     renderer.render(stage);
     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

If you run the code snippet, you'll notice the circle leaves trails, which is good. However I'd like to control the transparency of these trails. How can that this be achieved ?

What's the best way to draw transparent trails using PIXI.js ?

(Additionally, I get this warning in console:

```
[.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source
```

and destination textures of the draw are the same.

How can this be remedied ?)

**Update**

To Illustrate, here's the same idea using [p5.js](http://p5js.org):

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,300);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  //transparent rectangle
  fill(0,10);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  //shape that will leave trails because buffer isn't cleared completely
  fill(255);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I thought I could achieve this with a ColorMatrixFilter, but I couldn't find an exhaustive documentation (as it's arguments are different from the as3 ColorMatrixFilter). I will try with a GLSL shader as a CustomFilter next.
What's the equivalent using PIXI.js ? Ideally something that will be efficient and scale well (allowing easy trails for thousands of objects)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your p5 example, you can achieve the same result with PIXI using a single Graphics object. Not sure how well this will work with thousands of objects, but I wouldn't imagine the p5 one to perform any better since it does the same thing.

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(640, 480);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();
 
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
stage.addChild(graphics);

animate();

function animate() {
 var a = Date.now() * 0.001;

 var x = renderer.width * 0.5 + (Math.cos(a) * 200);
    var y = renderer.height * 0.5 + (Math.sin(a) * 200);

        //Draw a circle
 graphics.beginFill(0xFF9900);
 graphics.drawCircle(x-8, y-8, 16);
 graphics.endFill();

        //Draw background
 graphics.beginFill(0, 0.1);
 graphics.drawRect(0, 0, renderer.width, renderer.height);
 graphics.endFill();

   renderer.render(stage);
 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

---

Another approach is to combine this with the example using the RenderTextures. This may run faster with 1000 objects.

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(640, 480);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Container();

var renderTexture = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
var renderTexture2 = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
var outputSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(renderTexture);
stage.addChild(outputSprite);

var dot = new PIXI.Graphics();
dot.beginFill(0xFF9900);
dot.drawCircle(-8,-8,16);
dot.endFill();
dot.cacheAsBitmap = true;
stage.addChild(dot);

var bg = new PIXI.Graphics();
bg.beginFill(0, 0.1);
bg.drawRect(0, 0, renderer.width, renderer.height);
bg.endFill();
bg.cacheAsBitmap = true;
stage.addChild(bg);

animate();
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    var a = Date.now() * 0.001;
    dot.x = renderer.width * 0.5 + (Math.cos(a) * 200);
    dot.y = renderer.height * 0.5 + (Math.sin(a) * 200);

    // swap the buffers ...
    var temp = renderTexture;
    renderTexture = renderTexture2;
    renderTexture2 = temp;
    outputSprite.texture = renderTexture;

    renderTexture2.render(stage, null, false);
    renderer.render(stage);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you(+1), the second options works better (just tested with about 100 agents). Would you happen to have any tips on dealing with these warnings when rendering the buffer: ```[.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.``` ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza The code was missing a line `outputSprite.texture = renderTexture;` which swaps the buffers. I've updated my answer to fix that warning.

Answer (score 2):

The PIXI.Graphics object has an "alpha" attribute. Your dots can be transparent by adding

```
dot.alpha = 0.25; // this is the value in the as3 script you shared
```

Here's how it looks like:

```js
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(640, 480);
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

 var stage = new PIXI.Container();
 
 var dot = new PIXI.Graphics();
 dot.beginFill(0xFF9900);
 dot.drawCircle(-8,-8,16);
 dot.endFill();
 stage.addChild(dot);

 var renderTexture = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
 var renderTexture2 = new PIXI.RenderTexture(renderer, renderer.width, renderer.height);
 var currentTexture = renderTexture;

 var outputSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(currentTexture);
 stage.addChild(outputSprite);


 animate();

 function animate() {
  var a = Date.now() * 0.001;
  dot.x = renderer.width * 0.5 + (Math.cos(a) * 200);
  dot.y = renderer.height * 0.5 + (Math.sin(a) * 200);
  dot.alpha = 0.25;
  // swap the buffers ...
     var temp = renderTexture;
     renderTexture = renderTexture2;
     renderTexture2 = temp;

     renderTexture2.render(stage, null, false);

     renderer.render(stage);
     requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer (+1). I did try that (sorry should've mentioned). What I'm looking for is a solution that doesn't require setting alpha individually to every single display object in the scene.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Can you better explain what you are trying to achieve? If you don't want to set the alpha on every display object, you can just set it on the original Graphics object instead. Alternatively, you can set the alpha of the fill as the second parameter of beginFill `dot.beginFill(0xFF9900, 0.25);`

Comment: @Karmacon That works to a certain extent. I'm would like to do a boids simulations with a few thousand agents and I've tried the Graphics approach but it doesn't scale well. In gl or with pixels the same effect could be achieved by having a low alpha buffer clear color (e.g. drawing a low transparency rectangle as the background and the rest of the shapes on top). I'm not sure if this is clear, I've added an update